# Scroll the content of <object> tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using a web page where i am loading a external webpage into a div using object tag.However the content of the external page is overflowing and i am unable to see the whole content.
So i have tried to implement the auto scroll feature where the content of the object will scroll down in steps and when it reaches end it should scroll up,please find below the code i have used.But i am unable to get the auto scroll functionality :-(

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if ($("#objs").scrollTop() != $('#objs').scrollHeight) {
                $("#objs").scrollTop($("#objs").scrollTop() + 10);
            }
            else {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }); 
</script>
<body>
     <div id="siteloader">    <%--div to load site--%>
         <object id="objs" data="http://www.w3schools.com//" ></object>
     </div>
</body>
```

Please help me in implementing this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check $(window).scroll(function(e){....});

Comment: Also what is <%--div to load site--%>? If its comment, you should use <!-- comment -->

Comment: I understand what you mean by content is overflowing I see its coming up in small block.

Comment: yeah,its a comment.sorry for that .if you could able to understand the problem could you please help me on this??

Comment: sorry I meant to say I don't understand the part where you say content overflowing.

Comment: Content is overflowing means the page content is so big that object will introduce scroll bars,so i have to manually scroll down to see the content.This should be avoided and auto scroll up and down feature to be implemented using jQuery or javascript,thats exactly what i am seeking answer from this thread :-)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#objs')` is a JQuery selector, while `.scrollHeight` is a native JavaScript API. You have to add JQuery `.get()` to swtch back the JQuery object as DOM collection or set the array index right after the JQuery selector to make native JavaScript API works in JQuery selector:

```
// Example #1
$('#objs').get(0).scrollHeight

// Example #2
$('#objs')[0].scrollHeight
```

Comment: I am unable to get the result using the method what you have specified above.If it is working then could you please put a working demo (like JSFiddle) thanks