# Why the contents of the object tag are not scrolling automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, scrollbar

I have a webpage where i am loading a external webpage into div tag using object tag and it is working fine.the content of the webpage is overflowing and hence i need to implement auto scroll feature. I am **able** to implement the auto scroll feature to div tag but when i use the same logic for autoscrolling the object then it is **not working**.
Please find below the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if ($("#siteloader").scrollTop() != $("#siteloader")[0].scrollHeight) {
                $("#siteloader").scrollTop($("#siteloader").scrollTop() + 10);
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

and HTML markup is

```
<body>
    <div id="siteloader" style="height: 100px; width: 600px; border: 1px solid #ccc;
        overflow: auto">
        <object id="objs"  height="500px"  width="500px"  data="http://www.w3schools.com"></object>
    </div>    
</body>
```

i am able to scroll the **div** but i am unable to scroll the contents within object tag.

Please note that i am loading page from external website.

any suggestions??
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll the content of <object> tag using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047614/scroll-the-content-of-object-tag-using-jquery)

Comment: you have asked same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047614/scroll-the-content-of-object-tag-using-jquery

Comment: i didn't got the answer in the previous thread